# Error: Could not load plugin for terraform 0.14.3

Tags: devops, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.14.7

We are getting below error for our provider

> Error: Could not load plugin
>
> Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
> Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
> resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,
> don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.
> Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
> configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
> requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".
> Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to obtain
> schema: unknown provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"
> Authenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json

although we have also replaced the provider

```
terraform state replace-provider -auto-approve registry.terraform.io/-/aws registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws 
terraform state replace-provider -auto-approve registry.terraform.io/-/external   registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/external
terraform state replace-provider -auto-approve registry.terraform.io/-/null   registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null
terraform state replace-provider -auto-approve registry.terraform.io/-/random   registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random
terraform state replace-provider -auto-approve registry.terraform.io/-/template  registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template
```

apart from this we had also used required_providers but no luck

```
 required_providers {
        aws = {
        source = "hashicorp/aws"
        version = "3.49.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: try terraform init --upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below steps.

1. rm -rf ~/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/*
2. terraform init

Hope this helps.